# TypeError: expected string or buffer when trying to migrate database

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
    draft  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    publish = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    Updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=False)
    Timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicodde__(self):
        return self.Title

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        #return 'posts/%s/' %(self.id)
        return reverse('posts:detail', kwargs={'id':self.id})
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-Timestamp","Updated"]
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
                        "title",
                        "Content",
                        "image",
                        "draft",
                        "publish",

        ]
```

and terminal :

```
    jayu@broadwell-gt2:~/Desktop/trydjango19$ python manage.py migrate
    Operations to perform:
      Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, posts, auth, sessions
    Running migrations:
      Rendering model states... DONE
      Applying posts.0002_auto_20180526_0745...Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 342, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
/migration.py", line 123, in apply
        operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 62, in database_forwards
        field,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 221, in add_field
        self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 103, in _remake_table
        self.effective_default(field)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 210, in effective_default
        default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 728, in get_db_prep_save
        prepared=False)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1301, in get_db_prep_value
        value = self.get_prep_value(value)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1296, in get_prep_value
        return self.to_python(value)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1260, in to_python
        parsed = parse_date(value)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py", line 60, in parse_date
        match = date_re.match(value)
    TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

after successfully completing python manage.py makemigrations ,

when i trying to migrate then

TypeError: expected string or buffer 
error is occurs.

i did any mistake in data type or something else did wrong ?

what i did wrong here ?

Please help me...

any default value in models field getting wrong ?

Comment: Can you post the relevant migration file.

Comment: Probably a separate issue, but you misspelled `__unicodde__`..

Comment: Then how can I correct misspelled thing ??

Comment: @JaySuthar: you could look for documentation? The correct spelling is `__unicode__`. Not that this caused your problem.

Comment: @JaySuthar: the problem is caused by a migration step, and I suspect a wrong `default` value having snuck in somewhere. The exception shows that Django is trying to interpret an unsupported type as a date.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i have added one relevant file forms.py

Comment: @MartijnPieters just for trying purpose i had remove default from model field but still get same error.

Comment: I guess you might have passed an integer type value during makemigration step for your model, you can check your migrations for invalid type value assignment and If exists you can change that in migrations file itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think a quote from django docs about [DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield) could help you:

> The options auto_now_add, auto_now, and default are mutually exclusive. Any combination of these options will result in an error.